# Specifying conditions on the joined tables, how to AND the nested condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A Result has many Installations.

I want to find all Results which contain an Installation with `tool_id` of `123` AND an Installation with `tool_id` of `456`.

I know that the following gives me all Results with an Installation with `tool_id` of `123`:

```
Result.includes(:installations).where(installations: {tool_id: 123})
```

So I tried to chain another `where`, but it didn't work:

```
Result.includes(:installations).where(installations: {tool_id: 123}).where(installations: {tool_id: 456})
```

What's the best way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Result.includes(:installations).where('installations.tool_id in (?),', [123, 456])

Comment: I'm getting `Unknown column 'installations.tool_id'`. Is that syntax correct for nesting `tool_id` under `installations`?

Comment: Result.includes(:installations).where('installations.tool_id in (?)', [123, 456]) this syntax is correct if tool_id column is present in installations table. Do you want to say that tool_id column is part of results table? If yes, then replace installation.tool_id with results.tool_id

Comment: Yes, `tool_id` is present in the Installation table.

Comment: I think the problem may be that there is no `installations` column on Result. There is only a `result_id` on Installation, and the Result `has_many` installations.

Comment: Though it works for statements like `Result.includes(:installations).where(installations: {tool_id: 123})` because of ActiveRecord?

Comment: And regardless of that, won't your answer give me all installations with `tool_id`s of 123 or 456? I want all installations with `tool_id`is of 123 AND 456.

Comment: if you have relationship defined between results and installations like in Result mode has_many :installations and in Installation model belongs_to :result then the query mentioned by me should work. I have tried it out locally

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using finding one and then the other and then using `&`. It worked, but I don't think it's the best way to do it.

```
Result.includes(:installations).where(installations: {tool_id: 123}) & Result.includes(:installations).where(installations: {tool_id: 456})
```